# Pattern Clustering using Python

Tags: python, pandas, pattern-matching, hierarchical-clustering

I wanted to recognise all the patterns data can be present in "Subset" Column of following data frame.

DataFrame-

```
Name    Subset    
A-1001  0
A-1001  1
A-1001  2
B-1005  3
B-1005  4
D-1015  0
D-1015  1
D-1015  2
L-650   0 
L-650   5
L-650   6
V-895   3
V-895   4
```

Here in this data frame, Patterns for Subsets of A-1001, D-1015 Are matching, while B-1005, V-895 have same pattern. Pattern for L-650 is different.

i.e Output Example

```
Pattern#    Name
1           A-1001, D-1015
2           B-1005, V-895
3           L-650
```

How can I recognize these patterns using Python?

P.S There may be many unknown patterns.

Comment: What is a "pattern"? The number in Subset?

Comment: Yes. Subset (0,1,2); (3,4), etc are patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to perform a double `groupby`, once to aggregate the Subsets per name and form "patterns", and a second time to aggregate the patterns to group the Names:

```
import numpy as np

(df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)
   ['Subset'].agg(frozenset)      # use a tuple instead of frozenset if order matters
   .groupby('Subset', as_index=False)
   .agg(list)                     # use ', '.join instead of list to have a string
   .assign(Pattern=lambda d: np.arange(len(d))+1)
)
```

output:

```
      Subset              Name  Pattern
0  (0, 1, 2)  [A-1001, D-1015]        1
1     (3, 4)   [B-1005, V-895]        2
2  (0, 5, 6)           [L-650]        3
```

Comment: Please solve them
Q1- https://stackoverflow.com/q/70953148/17778275
Q2- https://stackoverflow.com/q/70966309/17778275