# Find all inputs belonging to a particular KNN class

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, output, knn

I have created a KNN based classification algorithm using sklearn Python.
The algorithm has created 4 classes named "1","2","3","4".
I want to give a list of inputs to the algorithm and predict in which class out of the four classes they might belong and print out the list of only those inputs belonging to class "1"

Trying to use:

```
review_3 = ["Loop","Loop No.", "Customer Tag"]

review_3 = vectorizer.transform(review_3)
print(type(review_3))
L = []

for i in review_3:
     if (knn.predict(i)==1):
         L.append(i)
print(L)
```

Algorithm correctly classifies the output classes but unable to get the required list.
Here required output is

```
L= ["Loop","Loop No."]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the required output by converting a list out of predicted outputs.
The input list and predicted list together create a dictionary. The values are compared for each keys according to required class name then to get the required list out back.